MAUI: Slider is not sliding properly
I have a slider in my UI and I am not able to slide it properly.
Below is the code:
<Slider 
    x:Name="watchme_slider"
    Grid.Column="1"
    BackgroundColor="White"
    MinimumTrackColor="#1c98d7"
    MaximumTrackColor="#9a9a9a"
    ThumbImageSource="ic_thumb_xx.png"
    ValueChanged="SliderValueChanged"
    Maximum="0.166666667"
    Minimum="0"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>

This slider is on a ContentView and below is the full xaml code:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
    xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="false"
    BackgroundColor="White"
    x:Class="MyProjectName.Pages.HomePage">

    <StackLayout 
        Orientation="Vertical">
        <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout>
                <Frame 
                    BorderColor="#ffffff"
                    BackgroundColor="#ededed"
                    Margin="10,10,10,5"
                    HasShadow="False"
                    CornerRadius="10"
                    Padding="5">

                    <StackLayout
                        Margin="5"
                        Orientation="Vertical">

                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="9.5*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Label 
                                x:Name="slider_timer_label"
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                Text=" "
                                Margin="0,0,0,5"
                                Padding="3"
                                HorizontalOptions="Start" 
                                HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" 
                                VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                                TextColor="#ededed">
                                <Label.FontSize>
                                    <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                        <OnIdiom.Phone>12</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                        <OnIdiom.Tablet>18</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                        <OnIdiom.Desktop>12</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                                    </OnIdiom>
                                </Label.FontSize>
                            </Label>
                        </Grid>

                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="9*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Label 
                                Margin="5"
                                HorizontalTextAlignment="End"
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                Text="0"
                                TextColor="Black">
                                <Label.FontSize>
                                    <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                        <OnIdiom.Phone>16</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                        <OnIdiom.Tablet>24</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                        <OnIdiom.Desktop>16</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                                    </OnIdiom>
                                </Label.FontSize>
                            </Label>

                            <Slider 
                                x:Name="watchme_slider"
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                BackgroundColor="White"
                                MinimumTrackColor="#1c98d7"
                                MaximumTrackColor="#9a9a9a"
                                ThumbImageSource="ic_thumb_xx.png"
                                ValueChanged="SliderValueChanged"
                                Maximum="0.166666667"
                                Minimum="0"
                                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                        </Grid>

                        <Label 
                            x:Name="watchme_timer_label"
                            Margin="5,10,5,10"
                            Text=" "
                            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                            TextColor="#ededed">
                            <Label.FontSize>
                                <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                    <OnIdiom.Phone>16</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                    <OnIdiom.Tablet>24</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                    <OnIdiom.Desktop>16</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                                </OnIdiom>
                            </Label.FontSize>
                        </Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                </Frame>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentView>                

I tried the slider on a demo project and it is working fine on it. I think the issue may be due to the parent layout of my UI. I have uploaded a demo project here for reproducing this issue.

"not able to slide it properly" - what does this mean?

@Jason When dragging the thumb of slider it is not moving.

From CarouselView document

By default, CarouselView will display its items in a horizontal orientation. A single item will be displayed on screen, with swipe gestures resulting in forwards and backwards navigation through the collection of items.

This issue is related to the scroll event conflict. When you scroll the Slide, your scroll event will be captured by the CarouselView's swipe gestures.
You can set IsSwipeEnabled="False" for your CarouselView, your Slider could be scrolled normally. If you need to switch other items in the CarouselView, you can use carouselView.ScrollTo(); to do it.
<CarouselView 
    x:Name="carouselView"
    IsSwipeEnabled="False"
    Loop="False">

By the way, if you do not want to set IsSwipeEnabled="False", you can use increase and decrease buttons to replace the slider.

The community has pointed out that there's a conflict between them for Android. But as a workaround, if you want to drag the slider and scroll the CarouselView at the same time, you may try using Maui Handler to deal with it.
Here's the relevant code,
#if ANDROID
    using Android.Views;
#endif


public partial class CarouselHomePage : ContentPage
{
    public CarouselHomePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ModifySlider();
    }

    void ModifySlider()
    {
        Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.SliderHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("MyCustomization", (handler, view) =>
        {
#if ANDROID
            handler.PlatformView.SetOnTouchListener(new SliderListener()); 
#endif
        });
    }

#if ANDROID
    public class SliderListener : Java.Lang.Object, Android.Views.View.IOnTouchListener
    {
        public bool OnTouch(global::Android.Views.View v, MotionEvent e)
        {
            if (e.Action == MotionEventActions.Down || e.Action == MotionEventActions.Move)
            {
                v.Parent.RequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            }
            else
            {
                v.Parent.RequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
#endif
}

Also, if you just want to use handlers for specific control instances, you may refer to customize a specific control instance.
Hope it helps!

Any using statements I need to add for this, I am getting errors for almost all lines.

Yes, there are some using statements because we use android native code. I will update my answer as soon as possible.

I've updated my answer and tested on my side. Please let me know if you have any question.
